# How can I slide the Tabs-menu right in boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a menu using class .
The menu created using this class is left aligned.
How can I align this menu to the right?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your code also

Comment: well, you can add a bootstrap class "text-right" on the menu but your question seems incomplete. Please add code for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for, can be achieved by giving `float:right` style to your `ul`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="float:right;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

but it will make your content of the paragraph to come just beside your menubar. To overcome that just put the `p` tag out of the `div`like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="float:right;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are going for but all you need is a

```
float:right;
```

in your css class I guess.

Comment: You need to add this css property on main element only.